# DOMxpath query didn't respond with the data through xml in php

Tags: php, xml, domxpath

getting data from query following-sibling::table/tbody/tr/td/font[2]/text() in DOMXpath doesn't show any data in php

Comment: What is content of your xml?

Comment: I am Scrapping a website for my work. these are the queries:                     $URL='http://find.cato.org/search?q=latest&op=Search&client=default_frontend&output=xml_no_dtd&proxystylesheet=default_frontend&sort=date%3AD%3AL%3Ad1&entsp=a__cato_policy_drew0115&wc=200&wc_mc=1&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8&ud=1&exclude_apps=1&site=web_collection';
$Looping='//div[@class="main-results"]/p[@class="g"] | //div[@class="main-results"]/blockquote[@class="g"]';
$date='following-sibling::table/child::tbody/child::tr/child::tr/child::td/child::font[2] | table/tbody/tr/td/font[2]/text()';

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please clerify it and add your code.